# While loop iterating only once while using api to post on users wall?

Tags: php, facebook, loops, while-loop, facebook-wall

I am using while loop to post on users wall through application. While loop executes only once and post on users wall once at a time. I wonder why this is happening.

```
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
        echo "posting in userwall";
        $facebook->api('/'.$data['postid'].'/feed?access_token='.$data['token_key'], 'post', $attachment);
    }
```

The above code executes only one time even if there are many rows. However when i comment second line "$facebook->api('/'.$data['postid'].'/feed?access_token='.$data['token_key'], 'post', $attachment);" it runs as many times it has rows. for eg

```
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
       echo "posting in userwall";
       //$facebook->api('/'.$data['postid'].'/feed?access_token='.$data['token_key'], 'post', $attachment);
    }
```

I have two rows data and it shows o/p two times. However while i use "$facebook->api('/'.$data['postid'].'/feed?access_token='.$data['token_key'], 'post', $attachment);" it runs only once why?

Comment: when you make lots of posts one after the other facebook sometimes sees this as spamming (especially if you making posts for the same user), and they will just ignore the posts... you should try placing a delay between posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$facebook->api('/'.$data['postid'].'/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

Comment: Can you explain how removing ?access_token='.$data['token_key'] works. It really didn't worked for me...

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot.